# Awstats: Combine HTTP and HTTPS logs

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, awstats, statistics

Plesk keeps the configuration files for AWStats in the following folder:

```
/usr/local/psa/etc/awstats
```

At the end of the configuration files for the domain for HTTP+S is the following line for custom changes as the files gets overwritten by Plesk:

```
/etc/awstats/awstats.conf.local
```

My question is now how could I combine both logs for HTTP and HTTPS in the log analysis for AWStats to product a combination of both? Means visitors for HTTP and HTTPS for the domain should be aggregated into one summary file of AWStats (without getting overwritten by Plesk).

Note: I'm aware of the following: [What should Server Fault do with questions about web hosting control panels?](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8055/what-should-server-fault-do-with-questions-about-web-hosting-control-panels) but this question is generally about AWStats, Plesk just plays the role of overwriting some configuration files, nothing deeply related to the question itself imho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following https://www.howtoforge.com/logresolvemerge.pl_merge_apache_access_logs

With Awstats there is a tool *logresolvemerge.pl* which allows you to merge different files in just one, very useful for your situation or where you have several webservers loadbalanced.

You should use it like

```
logresolvemerge.pl ${file1} ${..} ${filen} > ${resultfile}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change your logging settings so that both https and http requests are logged into the same file.

Comment: That's true in cases that are on-topic in Server fault. It might be that Plesk prevents it, and that's one reason control panels are off-topic here.